# Finding the integral $\int{\cos^{2}(x)dx}$ using $\int{x^{n}dx}=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Let me first find the integral normally:

**Attempt 1:**

$$\int{\cos^{2}(x)dx}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\int{(1+\cos(2x))dx}$$

$$\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sin(2x)}{4}+C\tag{1}$$

**Attempt 2 (using the power rule):**

$$\int{\cos^{2}(x)dx}$$

$$\frac{\frac{\cos^{2+1}(x)}{2+1}}{\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(x))}+C$$

$$-\frac{\cos^{3}x}{3\sin(x)}+C\tag{2}$$

$(1)$ & $(2)$ are not [equivalent](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=cos%5E2x). How can I find the integral correctly using the power rule?

**PS:** I'm a complete amateur in integration. I only understand differentiation (somewhat).

Comment: If you have $\int \cos^2(x)d\big(\cos(x)\big)$ then you can use the power rules. Is it enough for you?

Comment: It is **not** generally true that $\int (f(x))^n\, dx = \frac{(f(x))^{n+1}}{(n+1)f'(x)}$.

Comment: The power rule is $\int u^n\ du=u^{n+1}/(n+1)$, where $u$ is a function of $x$. You don't have the $du$, so the power rule doesn't apply.

Comment: Adding info to Gerry Myerson: You are applying the power rule with respect to $x$, not $\cos x$. That's why it failed.

Comment: 1. It is easy to forget that a 'rule'/theorem typically has condition(s) that need to be satisfied for its consequent ('result') to be applicable. Referring to your text, what are the conditions of the 'power rule'?  2. To integrate the required function, something like the reverse of the chain rule would be helpful...