# How to identify an ellipse quickly?

Tags: circles, conic-sections

*This question came in the Chittagong University admission exam 20-21*

Q) What is the geometric shape of the curve $17x^2-2xy+17y^2-104x-140y+446=0$ known as?

(a) Circle

(b) Parabola

(c) Hyperbola

(d) Ellipse

**My attempt:**

According to my book,

> $x^2+y^2=r^2$, $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$, $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$ ... (1)
>
> Each of the equations in (1) contains the terms $x^2$ and $y^2$ and
> their coefficients are equal. Each of the equations in (1) is a
> circle.
>
> $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$,
> $\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}=1$ ... (2)
>
> Each of the equations in (2) contains the terms $x^2$ and $y^2$ and
> their coefficients are unequal and have the same sign. Each of the
> equations in (2) is an ellipse.

The equation given in the question has the terms $x^2$ and $y^2$ and their coefficients are equal. So, I think the answer will be (a). However, [after I graph the equation in desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6jdyzaidty), we can see that the equation is an ellipse (even though the coefficients aren't unequal). To be an ellipse, don't the coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ have to be unequal? Why are my book's instructions not working?

Comment: It’s because of that pesky “2xy” term.

Comment: The key difference is the term $-2xy$ missing from your book equations. You probably need to learn a bit about quadratic forms and their diagonalization to get to the bottom of the matter. It turns out that in a suitably rotated coordinate system the equation will look like one from the book. For example, the vectors $(1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$ are orthogonal. Therefore we expect an equation like
$$4(x-y)^2+(x+y)^2=1$$ to represent an ellipse with semiaxes in the direction of those vectors. Expanding out, that equation becomes
$$5x^2-6xy+5y^2=1.$$ See the $xy$-term again.

Comment: Similarly $17x^2-2xy+17y^2=9(x-y)^2+8(x+y)^2$, explaining why this is an ellipse tilted 45 degrees. Other tilt angles are, of course, possible.

Comment: By the way, [tag:elliptic-curves] means something else. It is not entirely unrelated to ellipses, but it is a topic for quite a bit deeper math. Therefore the tag was inappropriate and I removed it.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant

Comment: [The usual moral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4365595/finding-the-integral-int-cos2xdx-using-intxndx-fracxn1n#comment9118726_4365595): if a theorem's condition hasn't been satisfied then of course it's invalid to assert its conclusion. $\quad$ Just for interest: a nonzero $B$ means that the conic has been rotated, and its angle of rotation equals either $45^\circ$ or
$\,0.5\arctan\frac B{A-C}.$ $\quad$ BTW, that Desmos graph sure looks circular to me.

Comment: @ryang Zoom a bit, it'll start to look like an ellipse.

Comment: [Unrotating a conic](https://www.andrews.edu/~rwright/Precalculus-RLW/Text/07-05.html). Incidentally, since every circle is an ellipse, if that exam had been perfectly set (no content nor logic errors nor having multiple correct options), then option A could've been eliminated at the outset.)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily compare it with the general equation to tell whether it is which conic .

Considering the equation of a second degree curve as follows:

$\ ax^2 + by^2 + 2hxy + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0 $

If $\ h^2 < ab $

It represents an ellipse.

If $\ h^2 = ab $ . It represents a parabola.

If $\ h^2 > ab $ . then it represents a hyperbola.

If $\ h = 0 $ and  $\ a = b $  then it represents a circle.

In your question one can compare to obtain $a = 17 ,  b = 17 ,  h = -2$

so we can clearly see $\  h^2 < ab  $ so it is an ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

Following the same idea, you can write the quadratic term as
$\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}$ with
$\mathbf{A}
=\begin{pmatrix}
17 & -1 \\ -1 & 17
\end{pmatrix}$
Since $\mathbf{A}$ is positive definite, this tells you that 'ellipse' should be the answer.